# Extract element based on where clause in jq json

Tags: json, jq

My Json structure is like below.

How can i extract id of project whose name is ansible using jq?

The json file is very big

https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/

```
  {
    "id": 38,
    "name": "ansible",
    "path": "ansible",
    "description": "Ansible playbooks, roles, and supporting tools repos"
  },
  {
    "id": 18,
    "name": "Analytics",
    "path": "analytics",
    "description": "Big Data Analytics projects"
  }
```

Answer (score 10):

Assuming your input is actually an array of those objects, you could do this:

```
$ jq --arg name "ansible" '.[] | select(.name == $name).id' input.json
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you indicate the input is very big you may want to use **first**.  This solution will return the id of the first match found and then stop.

```
 first(.[] | if .name == "ansible" then .id else empty end)
```

Comment: a variation on this answer (does not address OP question, but for other uses cases), if you want all occurrances and you want the whole document returned..

`.[] | if .name == "ansible" then . else empty end`